# Unable to import Mixin from Single File Component in Vue.js

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Laravel with Vue.js and Webpack / Laravel Mix.
I have Single File Components which should make use of Mixins.
The folder structure looks like this:

```
/app.js
/vue-components/Component.vue
/mixins/api/common.js
```

common.js defines a mixin like so:

```
export default {
   // all content goes here
}
```

And when I import it from `app.js` and console.log it, it shows the data:

```
import industries from "./mixins/api/common";
console.log(industries); // this shows the content
Vue.component(
    'some-component',
    require("./vue-components/Component.vue")
);
```

Within Component.vue I use `mixins: [ industries ],` and that gives me the following error:

`Component.vue?bb93:73 Uncaught ReferenceError: industries is not defined`

**Question 1:**
Is it not possible to declare mixins globally and reference them from within a component?

To solve the issue I tried importing the mixin directly within the component instead of the global app.js file. 
But `import industries from "./mixins/api/common";` within `Component.vue` throws the following error while trying to compile with npm run:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./mixins/api/common in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],"babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import","webpack-async-module-name"],"env":{"development":{"compact":false}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/vue-components/Component.vue
```

**Question 2:**
If I have to import the mixin from within the Single File Components, what should the path look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in [Vue Document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin), You can declare mixin globally

```
//- build your mixin
const mixin = {
  created: function () {
    var myOption = this.$options.myOption
    if (myOption) {
      console.log(myOption)
    }
  }
}

Vue.mixin(mixin)


new Vue({
  myOption: 'hello!'
}) 
// "hello!"
```

You can also import mixin to use for each component.

In above your `Component.vue`, import path is not correct.
You should do `import industries from "../mixins/api/common"`

Comment: thank you! My import path being incorrect was really stupid. Thank you.